# How do you find the path of a directory that contains one file but don't contain another file?

Tags: files, find

Right now my approach is to:

- find directories containing a.txt

  ```
  find -type f -iname "a.txt" | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' > a_paths.txt
  ```
- find directories containing b.txt

  ```
  find -type f -iname b.txt |  sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' > b_paths.txt
  ```
- print the difference

  ```
  comm -23 <(sort a_paths.txt ) <(sort b_paths.txt)
  ```

Is there some efficient way with a `find` one-liner?

Comment: Note that **every** shell code can be put on *one* line, so the concept of one-liner is not very useful.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Badly formulated on my side: I was looking for something that is iterating the file system just once -- is more efficient and that implied in my head that find needs to be run just once, thus I helped with request for "one-liner"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `find` supports `-execdir` and `-printf`:

```
find . -name a.txt -execdir [ ! -e b.txt ] \; -printf %h\\n
```

will look for files named `a.txt`, check whether they have a sibling `b.txt` file, and if they don’t, output the containing directory’s name.

Without `-execdir` or `-printf`:

```
find . -name a.txt -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    dir=${file%/*}
    [ -e "$dir/b.txt" ] || printf "%s\n" "$dir"
  done' sh {} +
```

It's also more efficient in that it doesn't run one command per file.

Comment: Wonderful, tested and it works!

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(D/e'{[[ -e $REPLY/a.txt && ! -e $REPLY/b.txt ]]}')
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' **/a.txt(D^e'{[[ -e $REPLY:h/b.txt ]]}':h)
```